# tensorboard fails to generate graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I run the following code to see the graph generated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
logs_dir = "/home/sukriti/Desktop/GIS/new_code"
a = tf.constant(2)
b = tf.constant(3)
x = tf.add(a, b)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_dir, sess.graph)
    print sess.run(x)
writer.close()
```

I ran the following command

```
$ python demo.py
$ tensorboard --logdir="logs_dir"
```

> Starting TensorBoard 54 at http://drsbhattac:6006 (Press CTRL+C to
>   quit)

Now clicking on the above link (Graph tab)I found the following message:

> No graph definition files were found

Can you please help me what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you opening tensorboard with `--logdir="logs_dir"` or `--logdir="/home/sukriti/Desktop/GIS/new_code"` as used in your script?

Comment: logdir="/home/sukriti/Desktop/GIS/new_code"